# Limit function of a power series with negative common ratio.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have this
$$A = \sum_{j=0}^\infty(-t^2)^j$$

where $t\in [-a,a] $ and $a\in(0,1)$

I can show its uniform convergence and hence its point wise convergence using the M-test. But I am asked to find it's limit function.

This would be ok if ;

$$A' = \sum_{j=0}^\infty(t^2)^j$$

where I could fix $t$ and find the sum to $\infty$.

The negative sign is throwing me off, I think I would be wrong in saying that;

> Since $A$ is pointwise convergent it has limit function given by $f(t) = \frac{1}{1-(-t^2)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be exactly right.

The formula for a geometric series works for *all* convergent geometric series, even those with negative common factor. If you go through the derivation for the formula, you'll see that nothing in it depends on the factor being positive.